# Codeigniter, OpenID and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, openid

I'm trying to use [Codeigniter OpenID library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/OpenID/) and everything work fine with default configuration of **CI** without `.htaccess`.

When I remove `index.php` by changing `config.php` and `.htaccess` I get **404 Page Not Found** when I try to verify my openid (http://ci.dlsb.eu/test/)

Can anybody tell me where I'm wrong?

**config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` attempts to create [`PATH_INFO`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) in a per-directory context, which, from what I can tell, occurs too late in the request processing phase to work correctly.

The best solution is to simply not do this, as CodeIgniter doesn't require it to function:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

CodeIgniter should be able to figure out what the proper request was on its own, provided that you left `$config['uri_protocol']` set to `AUTO`. If not, you should set it to either `AUTO` or to `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: Ok, i fixed my .htaccess, $config['uri_protocol'] is set to REQUEST_URI, but I still get the same error...

Comment: Yeah, I may have been a little off-base. It's because the URL the form submits to doesn't have a trailing slash, so CodeIgniter's routing is failing somehow. I'll check to see why that might be and let you know how you can fix it.

Comment: When I set $config['url_suffix'] = "/"; everything work fine. Thanks Tim!